# Material UI - Error: Invalid hook call using create-react-library + MUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, migration, material-ui

I've migrated from **Material Ui v3** to **v4** on a `create-react-library` project. This project is a dependency on others project to share components. When I want to display a **material-ui component**, I have an Error: Invalid hook call.

I explained my error here :

> https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/18482

Thanks in advance for your responses :)

Comment: And what was their answer there?

Comment: Same problem for me,

Im trying to create a component lib for remix using rollup, but I get invalid hook error. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

In your package.json Remove react and react-dom from "devDependencies"